# EKEventStore permission prompt

Tags: ios, ios6

According to the calendar and events programming guide from Apple:

On iOS 6 and later, we must request access to use the user’s Calendar database with the requestAccessToEntityType:completion: method after the event store is initialized.

It is also stated that the user is only prompted the first time the app requests access to an entity type; any subsequent instantiations of EKEventStore uses existing permissions. Your app is not blocked while the user decides to grant or deny permission.

My question here is: is there a way for us to prompt the user again to request access to an entity type?

It seems bad that I have to put a UIAlertView to ask the user to go to Settings and give the proper permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is now, you will not be able to prompt the user again, if the user said no the first time. They will need to go to settings to change their choice. So an alert is a way to do it.